# what is the relation between "data visualization" and "embedding"?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

I am reading several articles about metric learning lately. Sentences like "build better data visualizations via embedding" and "low-dimensional linear embedding of labeled data" pop up very oftenly. The question is, how to understand the meaning of "embedding" here? Is it the same as the "feature extraction"? Like find a good mapping to project the original space to a new space, such that in the new space, the distance measure would be easier to calculate? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Without any context or references this is very difficult to answer. An empty comment is that this may be common jargon in some field, but it's not universal jargon across all of statistical graphics or visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Embedding" in the machine learning data visualization context typically means finding a map from the source objects (usually either high-dimensional vectors or arbitrary objects endowed with some kind of distance/similarity function) to a 2- or 3-dimensional space for visualization purposes.

The goal here isn't usually to make distances easy to calculate in the new space; instead, it's so they can be visualized. For example, "locally linear embedding" is a fairly popular technique.

This is related to the general notion of metric embeddings, that is representing objects in one metric space by another metric space so as to minimally change the distances. One common use of that in recent machin learning work is approximate kernel embeddings. It's possible some of the things you've seen refer to this more general sense, though without references we can't know.